# Problem with yajra data tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement a datatable into my laravel project, I installed yajra datatables in the project and everything ..

I add these to the app.php :

```
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

but when I try to make a new datatable using the command

```
php artisan datatables:make Companies
```

I get this error : ***There are no commands defined in the "DataTables" namespace***.

any idea how to solve this !!

Answer (score 4):

To fix this, you need to install yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons

so run this command:
`composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons`

reference: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1392

Answer (score 2):

If *error*:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
```

You can try:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons:*
```

it works on `yajra/laravel/datatables-oracle:9.0`

Answer (score 0):

just do the 3 things

1. run this command "composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons"
2. paste this two line in  providers in config/app.php file:
   Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
   Yajra\DataTables\ButtonsServiceProvider::class,
3. run this "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables-buttons"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**
Look for this file in your project

```
vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js
```

The copy it and put it in your assets public folder and then make sure you include it as a scribe before

```
{{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
```

so, it should be like this

```
<script src="{{ url('/') }}/assets/js/buttons.server-side.js"></script>
{{ $dataTable->scripts() }}
```

and hopefully it will be fixed.

**SOLUTION 2**
Remove buttons.
On your build method in the datatable class, remove buttons by adding something like this

```
 ->parameters([
        'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
        'buttons' => [],
    ]);
```

So, the final thing should look like this

```
public function html()
{
    return $this->builder()
                ->setTableId('users-table')
                ->columns($this->getColumns())
                ->minifiedAjax()
                ->dom('Bfrtip')
                ->orderBy(1)
                -->parameters([
                    'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                    'buttons' => [],
                ]);
}
```

**CONCLUSION**
If you still get an error, go to inspect and see if there is any warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you already upgraded your Laravel version to Laravel 9

You will be needing the Yajra DataTables version: ^10

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"^10.0"
```

Modify the app.php

```
Service Provider & Facade 
Register provider and facade on your config/app.php file.

'providers' => [
    ...,
    Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
]

'aliases' => [
    ...,
    'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
]
```

Then publish,

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider"
```

After publishing the DataTablesServiceProvider

Install data tables button 9.0

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons:9.0
```

Then run

```
php artisan datatables:make Companies
```

Credits to the original author of Yajra / ArJay Angeles

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
```

in ***config->app.php*** add providers and aliases

```
'providers' => [
        ...
        Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
    ]
    'aliases' => [
        ...
        'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
    ]
```

***and run the commands***

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider"

composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

composer update

composer require maatwebsite/excel

composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
```

***Then you can create datatables***

```
php artisan datatables:make Companies
```